# Development Documentation

Tags: documentation, code-documentation

We are a development team and we need to document our code.
Each developer works on a part of the code which can be called as a module.
We need a documentation that has this specification

1. It should be easy to implement and use
2. Each developer documents her/his own work and when another developer needs to know about any module, he/she shouldn't be obliged to ask the original developer about the documentation. He/she should be able to find the document by herself/himself.
3. We should be able to search through entire documentation.

Have you any suggestion for this?

Comment: This really depends upon the language ecosystem. Specifying the language(s) and/or platforms may yield better responses. Also, "ancillary" documentation generation, handling, and storage strategies should likely be considered.

Answer (score 4):

Most languages have a way to produce documentation from code comments.  Java and JavaScript both have ways to convert comments into an API specification, such as Java's Javadocs.  It really just depends on what platform you're using.

Comment: Indeed. Same goes for the VS/.NET, Scala, Perl, Python, Ruby, etc. as well. The language and ecosystem really play a part in what the "accepted" (and easy to use) tools are.

Answer (score 1):

You talk about design decision, requirements and such?

Why not use a wiki (we use PmWiki) for such collaboration?